# How to access an ObjectMapper in a custom Deserializer in Jackson?

Tags: json, jackson, jackson-databind

We have a class `View` that serves as a variant: it may contain just a simple string, or a multilingual caption with an image.

Our API users should be able to send us via JSON these `View`s with one of the two ways:

```
{"view": "just a string"}
```

or

```
{"view": {"caption": {...some caption structure...}}, "icon": {...some icon structure...}}
```

We can achieve this using a custom deserializer:

```
@Override
public Display deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    TreeNode tree = jsonParser.getCodec().readTree(jsonParser);

    if (tree.isValueNode()) {
        return new View(((TextNode) tree).textValue());
    } else {
        MultilingualText caption = extractCaption(tree);
        Icon icon = extractIcon(tree, "icon");

        return new Display(caption, icon);
    }
}

private MultilingualText extractCaption(TreeNode tree) {
    TreeNode treeNode = tree.get("caption);
    // error handling removed for simplicity
    return mapper.treeToValue(treeNode, MultilingualText.class);
}
```

Please note that we are holding a reference to `ObjectMapper` inside a deserializer. This allows us to decouple deserializers: `ViewDeserializer` does not need to know anything about how or who will deserialize a `MultilingualText`, for example.

But this implies that we have to pass a reference to `ObjectMapper` to our deserializers with such nested logic (via constructor). This seems strange as we are already inside some parsing infrastructure that surely has to know about the current `ObjectMapper`.

The questions are:

1. Is there a way to obtain a reference to an `ObjectMapper` inside a deserializer (or, equally, a serializer) method from its parameters?
2. Is there a better approach to this, probably without the usage of an `ObjectMapper` reference altogether? After all, we are given a parser and the context.

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I have the same

Answer (score -1):

Try to check current token and depending on it's type (text node or object node) deserialize using different embedded deserializers. 
Injecting `ObjectMaper` inside deserializer is wrong, because usually you inject deserializers into mapper.

Here is some tutorial: 
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/jackson-objectmapper.html#custom-deserializer

Comment: Please try to be constructive -- "this is wrong" is not very helpful. If OP is asking how to access an `ObjectMapper` I'm sure they have a very valid reason to try to do so.